# Assign multiple pre-made textures on a model

Tags: texturing

I've very simple floor + doorway block made in Blender.

[image: Simple doorway]

Now I would like to add two different textures (as texture from file), one  to both sides of wall part and another one to floor part.

How I can do that? It doesn't matter if it's blender or cycles renderer just which one is easier to do with.

Comment: Do you know how to add multiple materials to an object? Do you know how to use UV maps?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh. Related video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liNGmdXsfbs.

Comment: @MrZak thanks, it looks like exactly what I was looking for.